# Jackson Object Mapper - "Missing type id " on concrete class deserialization

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, boot

When I try to deseriliaze a sub class for Jackson Maps. I am getting following exception.Probably,
I have a problem  JsonTypeInfo JsonSubType definition

Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve subtype of [simple type, class com.siemens.datamanagement.dto.macro.configuration.ObserverCaller]: missing type id property 'type' (for POJO property 'observerCaller')

I have following object structure

```
@Data
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ObserverCaller.class, name = "observerCaller"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = DynamicCaller.class, name = "dynamicCaller"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = FileCaller.class, name = "fileCaller")})
public abstract class AbstractCaller {

    private String type = "default";

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
}

These are sub classes.


@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonTypeName("dynamicCaller")
public class ObserverCaller extends AbstractCaller implements Caller {


    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return OBSERVER_CALLER.getDescription();
    }

}

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonTypeName("dynamicCaller")
public class DynamicCaller extends AbstractCaller implements Caller {

    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return DYNAMIC_CALLER.getDescription();
    }
}



This is class which I want to serialize caller object according to type attribute. This caller can be observercaller or dynamiccaller

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ReferenceCaller implements Caller {

    private AbstractCaller caller;

    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return REFERENCE_CALLER.getDescription();
    }
}


This is json object which I want to serialize [![json][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/By9OP.png
```